# SwiftUI : Display preview in canvas with conditional layout

Tags: swiftui

I'm building a layout with some conditional controls, depending on user preference.
For example, I'm displaying a Picker (segmented) only if the user has chosen to see it (user sets a Bool to true in UserDefaults on the settings page of the app).

I tried setting that Bool as a var or constant in my preview struct, and I managed to have my Picker displayed in the canvas, but I get an error : "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" :

[image]

Here's how I declare my Bool :

```swift
private var isBiqualif: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: kbiQualif) // kbiQualif is constant string set in a separate file to avoid typos
```

Here's how I display my Picker :

```swift
if isBiqualif { // User has activated this in settings
                Picker("", selection: $typeSelectorIndex) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< types.count) { index in
                            Text(self.types[index]).tag(index)
                          }
               }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    Divider()

                } //  End of if statement for dual rating Picker
```

And my latest preview attempt :

```
struct CreateTakeoffView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

     let myBool = true
        return CreateTakeoffView(isBiqualif: myBool)
    }
}
```

Any ideas what's going on here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make it `private`, such you hide var, so instead use

```
var isBiqualif: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: kbiQualif)
```

Comment: Man, that simple ! Thanks I learned something again about var scopes...